# Python command interpreter

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line, interpreter

I have a python script I would like to run from a bash script in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -c "$(< input_file)" &> output_file
```

In the python script I have some different methods, so the input file contains things like:

```
from script import *; method_1(); method_2();
```

The problem is, in both of the methods, they have an `input()` method that requires user input (this can't be changed).

So how can I pass an argument in the `input_file` (some kind of newline argument) so that it is passed on to the `input()` method within `method_1()` or `method_2()`?

Comment: Any arguments on the python command line following the argument to the `-c` are interpreted as arguments to pass to the python code (i.e. whatever code is in your `input_file`).  So you could make the code in your `input_file` read arguments from the command line and then send it whatever you like before the `&> output_file` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenient way to do this is with a "here document":

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash
python -c "$(< input_file)" &> output_file << END
3
4
END
```

Here it is in a self contained test case:

```
$ cat input_file
height = input("Height:\n")
width = input("Width:\n")
print "Area: ", height*width

$ bash myscript
(no output)

$ cat output_file 
Height:
Width:
Area:  12
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `input` function just reads from standard input.

So you should just be able to pipe (or redirect) data to that python invocation for `input` to pick up I would think.